# SvelteKit: How to protect page with www-authenticate header

Tags: svelte, basic-authentication, sveltekit

I am trying to build a site with svelte-kit that has a small admin section that only users with a username and password can access. What I have right now is an admin page `admin.svelte` and a page endpoint `admin.ts` which should return a 401 status with a `www-authenticate: basic` header when the user is not logged in, like so:

```js
import type { RequestHandler } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const get: RequestHandler = async () => {
    return {
        status: 401,
        headers: {
            'www-authenticate': 'Basic'
        }
    };
};
```

But when I open `/admin` the browser login prompt is not shown like I would expect with the authenticate header. When I look at the network traffic, I can see that the page request has the correct 401 status, but the authenticate header is missing from the response headers.

Contrary to that, the browser login prompt is shown when I navigate via client-side routing from `/` to `/admin`.

How can I get the server-rendered page to include authenticate header and show me the browser login prompt, like it does after client side navigation?

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I use `pnpm run dev`

Comment: I don't anything about how you run the application in the question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa What exactly do you want to know? This is a Svelte Kit site and currently I am running it locally with the buildin web server (via `pnpm run dev`). For the adapter I am currently using the default one `adapter-auto` and plan to deploy to vercel

Comment: Exactly this :) Does the error happen on both dev server and Vercel? Because it might be some sort of a web server issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend looking at the [`handle`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) hook to intercept requests and check for authentication.

```js
// hooks.ts
import type { Handle } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import { ADMIN_LOGIN } from "$env/static/private";

export async function handle({
    event,
    resolve,
}: Parameters<Handle>[0]): Promise<ReturnType<Handle>> {
    const url = new URL(event.request.url);

    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
        const auth = event.request.headers.get("Authorization");

        if (auth !== `Basic ${btoa(ADMIN_LOGIN)}`) {
            return new Response("Not authorized", {
                status: 401,
                headers: {
                    "WWW-Authenticate":
                        'Basic realm="User Visible Realm", charset="UTF-8"',
                },
            });
        }
    }

    return resolve(event);
}
```

Then in your `.env` file:

```bash
ADMIN_LOGIN="admin:password"
```

Make sure to also set `ADMIN_LOGIN` in your hosting providers environment variable system.

Comment: Suggesting to use `buffer.toString("base64")` instead of deprecated `btoa()`

Comment: If you want to do that, you can use `Buffer.from(ADMIN_LOGIN).toString('base64')` but Buffer has to be available in your environment